# How to notify parent's view model when child's view model property is changed?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a windows say

1. PhotoAlbums (Parent window)
2. PhotoAlbumProperty (Child)

On Photo Albums window I have combo box of list of photo albums, NewAlbum button, Save button, property button.

I want to enable save button only when my PhotoAlbum is in edit mode.
PhotoAlbum will go in edit mode when I add new photos in a album OR **if I change properties by clicking property button.**

I have properties,

`IsPhotoAlbumUpdated` in PhotoAlbumVM

`IsPhotoAlbumPropertyUpdated` in PhotoAlbumPropertyVM

```
IsSaveEnabled
{
   get return this.IsPhotoAlbumUpdated || this.SelectedAlbum.IsPhotoAlbumPropertyUpdated;
}

 in PhotoAlbumVM

<Button Name="BtnSave" Command="{Binding Save}"
                    ToolTip="{x:Static resx:Resource.ToolTipSave}" Focusable="True"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaveEnabled}">
```

Now when `this.SelectedAlbum.IsPhotoAlbumPropertyUpdated` gets changed then how will my parent view model i.e. PhotoAlbumVM know this?

I was thinking to use prism events, but for doing such smaller thing I don't want to use prism events.

Please suggest me alternate logic.

Comment: Event Aggregator  is not really hard. See the light, simple and useful version of Event Aggregator by @Rachel:
https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/

Comment: Yes, I implemented that. it leads to performance issue, we already have used that in our application in many places.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the child item's `OnPropertyChanged` event. Each time `SelectedAlbum` is changed, in `set` remove the handler from the old album unless it's null using `album.PropertyChanged -= MyPropertyChanged` and assign the handler to the new value using `value.PropertyChanged += MyPropertyChanged`. In `MyPropertyChanged` force update new value of `IsSaveEnabled`.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to `PropertyChanged` events to collection items on CollectionChanged. Providing your UI is bound correctly to the items in the ObservableCollection, you shouldn't need to tell the UI to update when a property on an item in the collection changes. You can do the collection of specific object or use the below implementation to do it across application if you have to do make consistent behavior.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections;

namespace VJCollections
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     This class adds the ability to refresh the list when any property of
    ///     the objects changes in the list which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    public class ItemsChangeObservableCollection<T> : 
           ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                RegisterPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
            }
            else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                UnRegisterPropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
            }
            else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                UnRegisterPropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
                RegisterPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
            }

            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void ClearItems()
        {
            UnRegisterPropertyChanged(this);
            base.ClearItems();
        }

        private void RegisterPropertyChanged(IList items)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in items)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                }
            }
        }

        private void UnRegisterPropertyChanged(IList items)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in items)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                }
            }
        }

        private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }
}
```