# WPF MVVM view not updated when viewmodels properties are

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Context :

I have a treeview with a separate details view injecting by PRISM library when I click on one of my treeviewitem (and I can update all properties of my item with it). All my items have a *Enabled* property.

Problem :

- When I update programmatically my viewmodels property, my object is updated. If I click on an other treeviewitem and come back to the first one, I see the property was updated.
- All the updates are good when I enable/disable the item using my details view (the foreground is going grey and the property is change)
- But in my case, when I try to update it by a command triggered by a contextMenu it doesn't trigger the view and all the updates... but my viewmodel property is updated...

What am I going wrong ?

I am using ObservableCollection in my treeview, maybe I need to change the type of my collection ?

I have my BaseViewModel who implements *NotifyPropertyChanged*

```
public abstract class NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(Expression<Func<object>> propertyExpression)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(GetPropertyName(propertyExpression)));
    }

    private string GetPropertyName(Expression<Func<object>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var unaryExpression = propertyExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;
        var memberExpression = unaryExpression == null ? (MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body : (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
        var propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;
        return propertyName;
    }
}
```

So I call the property change method, but Why my view is not updating then ?

```
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return Model.Enabled;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != Model.Enabled)
            {
                Model.Enabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Model.Enabled);
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is the code of my view (for the command)

```
<MenuItem Header="Enable/Disable this equipment" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.ToogleEquipmentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}" InputGestureText="CTRL+D"/>
```

And here is the code of my view (Hierarchical data template from my treeview)

```
<!-- ModuleItems > IP / Name -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type siemens:ModuleItemSiemensViewModel}"  >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Name="ItemIp" 
                      Text="{Binding Path=Ip}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenuEquipment}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enabled}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enabled}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text=" / " ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenuEquipment}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enabled}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enabled}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="ItemName" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenuEquipment}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                      Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enabled}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enabled}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

**EDIT :**

Here is the code from my viewmodel and models :
My real problem is when I update an Item (with my property enabled) it update the item, but my list (ModuleItems) is not updated, what I need to do to correctly implement MVVM and to make my fields automatically updated ?

```
public class ModuleParamSiemensViewModel : ModuleParamBaseViewModel
{
    #region Attributes

    private ObservableCollection<ModuleItemSiemensViewModel> _moduleItems;
    private ModuleParamSiemens _model;
    private string _moduleType;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public ModuleParamSiemensViewModel(ModuleParamSiemens moduleParam) : base(moduleParam)
    {
        this.Model = moduleParam;
        this.ModuleType = "Siemens";
        ModuleItems = new ObservableCollection<ModuleItemSiemensViewModel>();
        Initialize();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public new ModuleParamSiemens Model
    {
        get
        {
            return _model;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != _model)
            {
                _model = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Model);
            }

        }
    }
    public new ObservableCollection<ModuleItemSiemensViewModel> ModuleItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _moduleItems;
        }
        set
        {
            this._moduleItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => ModuleItems);
        }
    }
    public override string ModuleType
    {
        get
        {
            return _moduleType;
        }

        set
        {
            this._moduleType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => ModuleType);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public void Initialize()
    {
        foreach (ModuleItemSiemens item in this.Model.ModuleItems)
        {
            Add(new ModuleItemSiemensViewModel(item));
        }
    }

    public void Add(ModuleItemSiemensViewModel item)
    {
        ModuleItems.Add(item);

    }


    #endregion
}
```

Model :

```
public class ModuleParamSiemens : ModuleParam
{
    public new ObservableCollection<ModuleItemSiemens> ModuleItems { get; set; }

    public ModuleParamSiemens()
    {
        ModuleItems = new ObservableCollection<ModuleItemSiemens>();
    }


}
```

EDIT 2 :

Add ItemSiemensViewModel

```
public class ItemSiemensViewModel : ItemBaseViewModel
{
    #region Attributes
    private ItemSiemens _model;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public ItemSiemensViewModel(ItemSiemens item)
    {
        this.Model = item;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public new ItemSiemens Model
    {
        get
        {
            return _model;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != _model)
            {
                _model = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Model);
            }

        }
    }
    public new OPCInfo Opc
    {
        get
        {
            return Model.Opc;
        }
        set
        {

            if (value != Model.Opc)
            {
                Model.Opc = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Model.Opc);
            }

        }
    }

    public ProtocolInfoSiemens Protocol
    {
        get
        {
            return Model.Protocol;
        }
        set
        {

            if (value != Model.Protocol)
            {
                Model.Protocol = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Model.Protocol);
            }

        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    #endregion
}
```

ItemSiemens :

```
public class ItemSiemens : Item
{
    public ProtocolInfoSiemens Protocol { get; set; }


}
```

ItemBaseViewModel

```
public abstract class ItemBaseViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public OPCInfoBaseViewModel Opc { get; set; }

    public ItemBaseViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

Item

```
public abstract class Item
{

    public OPCInfo Opc { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to know for sure what all might be wrong. That said, your use of `Expression` to get a property name is pointless. You should use either the `nameof` operator, or (IMHO much better) the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute to obtain the name of the property being updated. Not that there's any indication here changing that will fix your problem, but you should fix it anyway (and maybe it will solve your problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

My bindings are correct (or at least it works)

The problem is that I used ObservableCollection collection and when an item is update in this collection it's not even fire an event to say that something has changed (it does for adding and removing items)

So I have implemented my own **ItemsChangeObservableCollection** (you can look this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33866549/8237280)

And now all my problems in all my app are solved !

Answer (score 0):

You are sending INotifyPropertyChanged on your `ModuleItemSiemensViewModel` for the property `Model.Enabled`. This does not make much sense, as nobody is listening on the VM (`ModuleItemSiemensViewModel`) for this change. The INPC interface does not allow such a kind of update. Every control listens on the same object that it's binding a property. That means you can only send PropertyChanged for properties that are in the same class/instance the interface is declared.

You have to move the `NotifyPropertyChanged` to the "Model" instance and call it there like this:

```
[DefaultValue(true)]
[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
public bool Enabled
{
    get
    {
        return Model.Enabled;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != Model.Enabled)
        {
            Model.Enabled = value;
            Model.OnPropertyChanged(() => Enabled);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: All that `OnPropertyChanged()` does is use the name of the property from the expression passed. The name of the `Model.Enabled` property is the same as the name of the `Enabled` property, so while I agree the implementation is incorrect, it doesn't seem so in a way that would explain a lack of updating.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I don't understand in why my implementation is incorrect ? When I Change my ViewModel, I need to reflect the change in my model right ? Here, I found my bug, when I use a collection, the viewmodel type is different from the model type and I don't know how to reflect it in my model (I update my viewmodel from my view, but I don't know how to do it...) I will update my post with the collection.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes you are right. The "Name" that is send is the same but it is very important on which object the OnPropertyChange method is called. But your Comment on the OP's post is also correct. The Xaml code does not make sense as all bindings are directed to: ´siemens:ModuleItemSiemensViewModel.Enabled
that he did not included into the code example.

Comment: @JP: _"it is very important on which object the OnPropertyChange method is called"_ -- it is important but the OP's code does not have a problem in that respect. The property object is used only for the name. When the property is raised, they still pass `this` for the sender, and they still use the current instance's `PropertyChanged` event (which is much more important...event handlers often never use the `sender` parameter).

Comment: Sorry I have just copied the enabled property, I have now edited my post, you will see all my item classes (viewmodels & models) 

@PeterDuniho I have done my code like that because I saw some post who  said we must not touch our model class and all the propertyChanged and so on need to be on viewmodel only. So, Why I need to do it in model and I can't just do it in viewmodel ?

Comment: @Karakayn: you can do whatever you want, if it works. Some simple programs don't need separate model and view model. As for your edit, the code you posted is neither minimal nor complete. Please read **[mcve]**. See also [ask], and the articles linked at the bottom of that page for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.